# is there a way to execute if statement for null values

Tags: r

Not sure why i am getting this error. Can we not execute this statement

```
asd <- c()
asd1 <- c()

if(asd == asd1)
{
  pr <- 0
} else{
  pr <- 1
}
Error in if (asd == asd1) { : argument is of length zero
```

Can we not execute null values here? Because is asd is also 0 and asd1 is also 0. Also I do not need to use length(asd) == length(asd1). But asd == asd1 should work right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use all function,

```
asd <- c()
asd1 <- c()

if(all(asd == asd1)){
  pr <- 0
} else{
  pr <- 1
}

> pr
[1] 0
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you are trying to compare nothing to nothing. if you don't want to use length but actually want to check if both vectors are the same:

```
identical(asd,asd1)
```

Answer (score 0):

like most of the r functions, "==" is a vectorial function in R. Therefore `==`(x,y) compares the elements of x and y, returning a vector of the same size.

As stated by dvd280, `identical` is the "strict equality" between objects, that test that **everything** is *exactly* the same (by everything i mean everything ; every element of the structure must be the same).
Note : it doesn't check that the 2 objects are stored at the same place in the memory.

`all.equal` (with some arguments) checks the equality of everyone.

vectorial logic is something that is often seen in R ; by example

```r
c(TRUE,TRUE)&c(TRUE,FALSE)
```

returns

```r
c(TRUE,FALSE)
```

which is something fine because it is a language made for statistics : it relies on vectors, not variables which, in fact, in r, are length 1 vectors.